# Autologin not working on GDM with Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, gdm, auto-login

I would like to know how to make GDM to autologin with the default (and only) account. I use it with Gnome3 on my 2 machines (one with 12.04 and the other with 11.10).

I have selected to auto-login on the System Settings but it doesn't work.

PS: Installing kdm or lightdm is not a solution since I prefer GDM.

Answer (score 1):

GDM on these systems has a bug but there is a workaround.

Open the file with editors whichever you'd like to use:

```
gksu gedit /etc/gdm/custom.conf
```

Add these options to that file like this:

```
# GDM configuration storage
#
#See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
#Enabling automatic login
AutomaticLoginEnable = true
AutomaticLogin = YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME
.  
.
```

Then save and reboot and check if your machine could accept "auto-login" as normally...

Hope this helps
[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2064778)

Comment: There is no custom.conf file. Can I safely create one or will this overwrite the other PostSession PostLogin and PreSession folder/files ?

Comment: Create a new custom configuration. If it does not work what is there to loose. YOU CAN ALWAYS DELETE THAT.

Comment: should be #Enabling automatic login